# bash imagemagick import screen capture with minimized and maximized windows

Tags: image, bash, import, screenshot

I want to do a simple full screen capture from a bash script in ubuntu. This:

```
import -window root screen.png
```

from [imagemagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/www/import.html) worked fine, untill--- I switched to a laptop with an external display connected. Now the captured image is not what is shown on the screen, but instead it shows the different windows. Is there a way to control this behavior of `import`, or do I need another tool?

Edit:

It is very important for me that no mouse-click is needed, as the script is run without human interaction.

**Edit**:

The real problem is not what I original thought, but it is an error of `import` - It can not handle maximized or minimized windows correctly.

Answer (score 3):

Specifying display *and* window will remove the need for mouse click:

`import -display :0.1 -window root -colorspace RGB -quality 80 screendump.jpg`

Comment: I have been doing a lot of testing. For me it seems like that only the last of `-display :0` and `-window root` is in effect. That is either mouse-click, or wrong display.

Comment: Actually, I am not sure that `-display :0` is working, as it forces me to click in the window.

Comment: You need ofcourse change value of /display/ to reflect the screen in question. -display and -window are not reciprocals.

Answer (score 1):

Tell it to use a specific screen.

```
import -display :0.1 ...
```

Comment: This is working, but here a mouse-click is needed. :o( I can not find any documentation on when a mouse-click is needed or not.